# Visual Basic Movie Program

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a weird issue with this VB program I'm working on for class. I'm honestly not entirely sure why I'm running into the problem, because I've done other assignments with ease that were relatively similar to this. The program is designed to allow me to add certain movies from the store (left list box) to the cart (the right list box.) You can see that I added Spider-Man two times (because who doesn't like Spider-Man?) and it did correctly show the name and the $2 each time. However the first label box in the bottom should be accumulating each time I add the movie to the box, but it stays firm at the first movie I pick. If I were to pick any of the other movies, which are all more expensive, it will still stay at the first movie I picked.

EDIT: I should add, I was having the same issue before I moved some parts of the code into their respective functions.

[image]

Public Class mainForm

```
Public strMovies() As String =
        {"Spider-Man", "Daredevil", "Hulk", "The Punisher", "Spider-Man 2",
         "Fantastic Four", "Spider-Man 3", "Iron Man", "The Amazing Spider-Man", "The Wolverine"}
Public intMoviePrices() As Integer =
    {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}

Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim moviecost As Integer
Dim movietax As Double
Dim numberdvds As Integer
Dim shippingcharge As Double
Dim netcost As Double
Dim movieChoice As String


Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstCom.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub


Public Function calculateTotals(movieChoice) As Integer



    moviecost = moviecost + intMoviePrices(movieChoice)
    movietax = (moviecost * 1.04) - moviecost
    If numberdvds >= 5 Then
        shippingcharge = 5
    Else
        shippingcharge = numberdvds
    End If
    netcost = movietax + moviecost + shippingcharge

    lblgrosscost.Text = moviecost
    lblsalestax.Text = FormatNumber(movietax, 2)
    lblshipping.Text = shippingcharge
    lblnetcost.Text = netcost

    Return moviecost
    Return movietax

End Function

Public Function addMovie() As String




    movieChoice = lstCom.SelectedIndex

    For X = LBound(strMovies) To UBound(strMovies)
        If lstCom.SelectedIndex = X Then
            lstCom2.Items.Add(strMovies(X) & " $" + intMoviePrices(movieChoice).ToString)
            numberdvds += 1
            Call calculateTotals(movieChoice)

        End If
    Next

End Function

Public Function removeMovie() As String



    For X = LBound(strMovies) To UBound(strMovies)
        If lstCom2.SelectedIndex = X Then
            lstCom2.Items.Remove(lstCom2.SelectedItem)
            numberdvds -= 1
            Call calculateTotals(movieChoice)

        End If
    Next





End Function

Private Sub mainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load




    lstCom.Items.Add("Spider-Man")
    lstCom.Items.Add("Daredevil")
    lstCom.Items.Add("Hulk")
    lstCom.Items.Add("The Punisher")
    lstCom.Items.Add("Spider-Man 2")
    lstCom.Items.Add("Fantastic Four")
    lstCom.Items.Add("Spider-Man 3")
    lstCom.Items.Add("Iron Man")
    lstCom.Items.Add("The Amazing Spider-Man")
    lstCom.Items.Add("The Wolverine")
    lstCom.SelectedIndex = 0


End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    Call addMovie()

End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click

    Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click

    Call removeMovie()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You may want to change your tag from VBA to VB.Net or the Visual Basic derivative you are using, thats not a VBA form :).

Comment: @Dan Donoghue it just may be on steroids...

Comment: Thank you Dan, that may be why I was getting the downvotes, or because it was a stupid question. I appreciate your help I'm toying with your answer currently!

Comment: In  `addMovie` you'll want to move your call to `calculateTotals(movieChoice)` outside of the IF block. Currently all your movies are free except for Spider-Man

Comment: just passing by to say, _I don't like spider-man movie_

Comment: @Baby You should be put in the corner for saying something like that!

Comment: @Baby that's a crime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another answer as this is the second question. I have modified your code but can't test as I don't have the project.

Please check it out and report back. Note you need to put some smarts into the removeMovie routine to work out the cost and tax, refer to what I did to the addMovie function to get an idea.

The calculate totals routine basically just formats and posts the data, the actual numbers are worked out when things are added / remove. I have removed the MovieChoice variable being passed into it as it is no longer relevant.

```
Public strMovies() As String =
        {"Spider-Man", "Daredevil", "Hulk", "The Punisher", "Spider-Man 2",
         "Fantastic Four", "Spider-Man 3", "Iron Man", "The Amazing Spider-Man", "The Wolverine"}
Public intMoviePrices() As Integer =
    {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}

Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim moviecost As Integer
Dim movietax As Double
Dim numberdvds As Integer
Dim shippingcharge As Double
Dim netcost As Double
Dim movieChoice As String


Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstCom.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub


Public Function calculateTotals() As Integer
    If numberdvds > 4 Then
        shippingcharge = 5
    Else
        shippingcharge = numberdvds
    End If
    netcost = movietax + moviecost + shippingcharge
    lblgrosscost.Text = moviecost
    lblsalestax.Text = FormatNumber(movietax, 2)
    lblshipping.Text = shippingcharge
    lblnetcost.Text = netcost
End Function

Public Function addMovie() As String
    movieChoice = lstCom.SelectedIndex
    moviecost = moviecost + intMoviePrices(movieChoice)
    movietax = movietax + (intMoviePrices(movieChoice) * 0.04)
    For X = LBound(strMovies) To UBound(strMovies)
        If lstCom.SelectedIndex = X Then
            lstCom2.Items.Add (strMovies(X) & " $" + intMoviePrices(movieChoice).ToString)
            numberdvds = numberdvds + 1
            Call calculateTotals()
        End If
    Next
End Function

Public Function removeMovie() As String
    'Need to add code to remove cost and tax here
    For X = LBound(strMovies) To UBound(strMovies)
        If lstCom2.SelectedIndex = X Then
            lstCom2.Items.Remove (lstCom2.SelectedItem)
            numberdvds = numberdvds - 1
            Call calculateTotals()
        End If
    Next
End Function

Private Sub mainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For X = LBound(strMovies) To UBound(strMovies)
        lstCom.Items.Add (strMovies(X))
    Next
End Function

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Call addMovie
End Function

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Function

Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
    Call removeMovie
End Function
```

Comment: You are my hero. Not only did I understand your changes, but I was able to manipulate what you had to do what I wanted, and complete the project. I couldn't appreciate your time more!!!!!!

Comment: @CullinMcGrath you can ask for his bank acc number, or maybe address to post a dozen of beer :D

Answer (score 2):

You are resetting movie cost each time you calculate as it is relative to that function only.

Move this:

```
Dim moviecost As Integer
```

Outside of the function for a quick fix but to do it properly I would leave it in there and calculate from the basket every time, the reason I would do this is because if you remove something from the cart you don't remove the price. Best to dynamically calculate based on the cart contents every time a change is made.

Also you can replace ALL of this:

```
If lstCom.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
    lstCom2.Items.Add ("Spider-Man " + "$" + intMoviePrices(movieChoice).ToString)
    Call calculateTotals(movieChoice)
ElseIf lstCom.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
    lstCom2.Items.Add ("Daredevil " + "$" + intMoviePrices(movieChoice).ToString)
ElseIf lstCom.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
    lstCom2.Items.Add ("Hulk " + "$" + intMoviePrices(movieChoice).ToString)
ElseIf lstCom.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
    lstCom2.Items.Add ("The Punisher " + "$" + intMoviePrices(movieChoice).ToString)
ElseIf lstCom.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
    lstCom2.Items.Add ("Spider-Man 2 " + "$" + intMoviePrices(movieChoice).ToString)
ElseIf lstCom.SelectedIndex = 5 Then
    lstCom2.Items.Add ("Fantastic Four " + "$" + intMoviePrices(movieChoice).ToString)
ElseIf lstCom.SelectedIndex = 6 Then
    lstCom2.Items.Add ("Spider-Man 3 " + "$" + intMoviePrices(movieChoice).ToString)
ElseIf lstCom.SelectedIndex = 7 Then
    lstCom2.Items.Add ("Iron Man " + "$" + intMoviePrices(movieChoice).ToString)
ElseIf lstCom.SelectedIndex = 8 Then
    lstCom2.Items.Add ("The Amazing Spider-Man " + "$" + intMoviePrices(movieChoice).ToString)
ElseIf lstCom.SelectedIndex = 9 Then
    lstCom2.Items.Add ("The Wolverine " + "$" + intMoviePrices(movieChoice).ToString)
End If
```

With this:

```
For X = LBound(strMovies) To UBound(strMovies)
    If lstCom.SelectedIndex = X Then
        lstCom2.Items.Add (strMovies(X) & " $" + intMoviePrices(movieChoice).ToString)
        Call calculateTotals(movieChoice)
    End If
Next
```

Then put this at the top of that function:

```
Dim X As Integer
```

Comment: could I ask for advice on the best way to calculate from the basket? Your reasoning makes sense to me.

Comment: Actually save yourself some time. 1) Make the MovieCost a module level variable (Move it outside any functions or subs) 2) When a movie is added do this: moviecost = moviecost + intMoviePrices(movieChoice) 3) when a movie is removed, do this: moviecost = moviecost - intMoviePrices(movieChoice). Should fix all the issues for you. Finally always do this lblgrosscost.Text = moviecost when you change MovieCost

Comment: Also check my edit in my answer. I chopped down that massive if for you.

Comment: That is awesome. I actually already had that time saving idea in place, however now my concern is that when I go to calculate tax, shipping charge, and net total with this it's going to really be screwed up if I remove anything. Or perhaps just calling the calculation after every remove would still be OK? As for your edit, thank you SO much.

Comment: No worries, always happy to help. With your tax, your thoughts are correct, calculate it every time you update moviecost, when you add or remove from moviecost  you will be able to work out what to add or remove from Tax, keep in mind you will also want the Tax variable at the module level.

Comment: Also another FYI you can save some code by putting part of this function in a loop similar to the one I posted above: mainForm_Load

Comment: sorry to bother you again, I know you've helped me a ton, but after taking your code it's not going so well. I'm attempting to code the remove movie function, but there's quite a few issues. I attempted to take your shortened version of the If/Else and flip it for the second list box to remove, however it just seems to accumulate more no matter what I do. This is what I'm working with:
http://pastebin.com/CV8aNgaG

Comment: Edit your original post to update the code with what you currently have and I will take a look for you :).

Comment: in the past I was yelled at for editing the post with changes, so people couldn't learn, but I did it anyway. What I have there is my 2nd attempt, I also tried to just manually change everything line by line but it actually turned out to be a bigger disaster. This is proving to be an incredibly difficult assignment. =\

EDIT: My thought with that was if I just removed the movie and called the function, it would pretty much do all the work for me!